# How does Python check for indentation errors?

Tags: python, passwords, indentation

```
import itertools
import string

file = open('list.txt', 'w')

def guess_password(real):
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
    attempts = 0
    for password_length in range(1, 9):
        for guess in itertools.product(chars, repeat=password_length):
            attempts += 1
            guess = ''.join(guess)
            if guess == real:
                return 'password is {}. found in {} guesses.'.format(guess, attempts)
            print(guess)
            file.write(guess + attempts # Unexpected indent error... WHY?!

print(guess_password('your password'))
command = input("()")
```

I commented where the error is being called. I am trying to make a program to give me a list of possible passwords and put them into a notepad file

The full error traceback is as follows:
File "Pass_Crack_List.py", line 16
file.write(guess + attempts) #Unexpected indent error.., WHY?!
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Also I have tried to backspace until the previous line and then hit enter, the error persists

---

#### Solved

**The error has been fixed. It gave me the error 3 lines too late (it was actually line 13).**

Comment: Did you miss your right parenthesis on the line where you commented?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: FIXED - The errors have been fixed and yes, i did miss my parenthesis on the line where i commented i just wasn't paying attention to that error at the time

Answer (score 0):

Try backspacing the error line until it is on the previous line, then press ENTER. If that doesn't fix it, maybe check to see if you are mixing tabs.

Comment: I have tried this and the error persists, any more ideas?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I went over my entire code from top to bottom and found the issue

Answer (score 0):

Possible mix use of tabs with blank, try to run your sciprt as follows: `python -tt your_script.py`

This will tell your errors if you mix tabs and blank, a more better habbit is to configure your editor to automatically change tabs to blanks.

Furture more, introduce [flake8](http://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/) to check your code, this will make your code a static check to get ride of potential issues.

Comment: Thank you that worked, I updated my code and the error persists. I gave a traceback of the error.

Comment: The output give you everything: `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`. If `python -tt your_script.py` still cannot pass after you modify, this means you still not do that correctly. You need to setup a new python file, and carefully enter you code one charactor by one charactor, don't use tab and space together. If you use vim, you can use `set list` to see the unvisiable space and tab. Anyway, please configure your editor to automatically replace tabs to space.

Comment: I figured out the issue. It gave me the error 3 lines too late. Not sure why but i fixed it

Comment: A good start, anyway vim notepad++ pycharm sublime all have settings to change tab to space, this is the way to avoid this issue forever